# How to make a function not ask for additional input based on initial input

Tags: c++

I need to make a program that reads in the users weight/height.

The user needs to be able to input a number and then a unit of measurement right after. This can be in feet/inches, meters, or cm.

I've gotten all that to work, but the user should also be able to write something such as 5' and have the inches be optional.

Here's the problem I'm having:

I have two variables I'm using for user input, one double (height), and one string (unitHeight). that works fine for m and cm, but for feet/inches I needed to add two more since the user needs to input two strings and two numbers (I kept it as doubles for simplicity's sake).

so I used an if statement:

```
if (unitHeight == "'"){
    cin >> height2;
    cin >> unitHeight2;
}
```

The problem is that I need to make it so that when the user inputs x' (x being whatever number), the program doesn't ask for any further input.

Comment: You should get the entire line and parse that. With an actual line, you can check whether the next two tokens are a number and "

Comment: If you stop after the `5'`, how would somebody enter `5'2"`?

Comment: I don't think you can just compare against a "" block.

Comment: i dont think ive made myself clear. the user may enter 5' and press enter, and it will accept it as 5 feet 0 inches by default, or the user can put in 5'2" and it will then accept it as 5 feet 2 inches.

Comment: It might not be a very neat solution but maybe you could use regular expressions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What to do depends a bit on what other input (if any) might come after the height, and how you want to handle errors, but to get you started:

```
int height2 = 0;
if (unitHeight == "'" && cin >> height2)
{
    if (!(cin >> unitHeight2))
    {
        std::cerr << "hey, " << height2 << " what?  give me units baby!\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // if we get here, then we have height2 and unitHeight2 to work with...
    ...

}
else if (cin.eof())
{
    // might have hit EOF without inches, that could be legal - depends on your program
    ...
}
else
{
    // saw some non-numeric input when expecting height2 - is that ok?
    ...
}
```

Since you posted, you've added a comment saying that you specifically want this input on a single line, after which the user can be expected to press enter.  To handle that, surround the above code with `std::string line; if (getline(std::cin, line)) { std::istringstream iss(line); >>above code goes here<< } else { ...couldn't read a line of input...}`.

Separately, you say:

> the user needs to be able to input a number and then a unit of measurement right after. this can be in feet/inches, meters, or cm. ive gotten all that to work

...I hope so, but note that it's a bit tricky when supporting e.g. 5'11" and 180cm, as `cin >> height1 >> unitHeight1`, when `unitHeight1` is a `std::string`, will read "'11".  If you make `unitHeight1` a `char` then it will tend to read only the "c" from "cm", so neither type works for both notations.  You'd best read a char then use it to decide whether to read another....

Comment: wait. I'm kind of a c++ nooby here. How is comparing unitHeight against `"'"` going to work? I thought `""` returned pointer to the data for that string (of chars). Or am i misunderstanding something?

Comment: the way i've slithered my way around all the different types of units is i have a double (height) and a string (unitHeight), and the user inputs say 200cm or 1.5m or 5.8feet, all of this is then checked in a method and converted ultimately to meters, since thats what im working with for further calculations.
the user can also input 5'7" for example
the way i did this, i explained above, with an if, and if unitHeight is ' then it allows for another double and another string input being the inches and the double quotes.
i just need to figure out how make the user not NEED to enter inches.

Comment: @BWG: in C++, `std::string` variables may be compared intuitively (i.e. with `==`, `!=`, `<` etc.) to string literals (i.e. double quoted ASCIIZ textual constants of type array-of-`const`-`char`): that's because the `std::string` instantiates a templated class for which there's a "user-defined" (Standard-library-provided) `operator==` that accepts a `const char*` as right hand side argument, but knows to do a `strcmp()`-ish operation internally.

Comment: @user3192656: " i just need to figure out how make the user not NEED to enter inches." - that's what `&& cin >> height2` does... determine whether they specified another number or not, if not - no worries, it falls down to one of the `else` clauses....

Comment: @TonyD Well. Templates and overloading. Messy stuff. I think the phrase "everything you think you know is wrong" applies to me here. Can you overload a typecast? Can you overload precedence of operators? Can you overload promotion of things?

Comment: @BWG: In practice, templates aren't relevant to how the `operator==` works... I just mentioned them because they're there in this particular case: `std::string` in an instantiation ala `std::basic_string<char>`, so you can make "string" classes for wide character types etc..  More generally, classes can have constructors from another type (the `explicit` keyword prevents accidental conversion), and there's a casting operator notation too - `operator T()` - so you can control which conversions happen when (but it isn't always possible to handle every situation intuitively).

Comment: @TonyD WHAT. So I could have a std::string of... bignums? What a thought, what a thought.

Comment: @BWG: yeah - it's an amusing thought, but quite possible...! :D  `typedef std::basic_string<BigInt> bi_string;` or whatever....

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
string height;
cin >> height;

for(int i = 0; i < height.size(); i++) {
    if(height[i] == "'"[0]) {
        cout << "It's ok!" << endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: why? as far as i can tell, that does nothing i need it to.

Comment: This code will identify when you will have a "'". So, you will know that after it, you will have the inches (forget about that "break;").

Comment: Thanks for the input but I don't need a for loop. I know for a fact that the input will be double, string, double, string (they'd only really be ints but I kept them as doubles for the calculations needed afterwards, and I didn't feel like type casting) the problem I am having is that the user needs to be able to do 5'7" or just simply 5' and hit enter and will not be asked for an inch value

Answer (score 0):

Read the stdin one line at a time. Process each line. If a line contains a second number (for height) and second string (for the unit), then you have the feet+inches specification. Otherwise, you just have one number and one unit.

```
const int maxLength = 200;
while (true)
{
   char line[maxLength+1];
   std::cin.getline(line, maxLength);
   if ( !cin.good() )
   {
      break;
   }

   std::istringstream str(line);
   double height1;
   std::string unit1;
   double height2;
   std::string unit2;
   bool secondHeightFound = false;
   str >> height1 >> unit1 >> height2;
   if ( str.good() )
   {
      str >> unit2;
      secondHeightFound = true;
   } 
}
```